# Set TextBlock.Text to string containing <LineBreak>

Tags: silverlight, xaml, textblock, line-breaks

I have a string that I am reading from the database and binding it to a TextBlock control in a XAML (Silverlight app). The string that's coming from the database already has  elements in the string. A sample string is this: `Microsoft's TechEd conference is the largest annual conference for introducing IT professionals and developers to currently shipping and near-term Microsoft technologies.<linebreak><linebreak>Designed for those who build, deploy or operate solutions based on Microsoft technologies.`

When the string is rendered the  appear as text and not as line breaks (spaces). How can I get the TextBlock control (or any other control) to display the spaces based on  when rendering the text?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do a Regex match and replace on the string before binding it to the TextBlock.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   static string ModifyInput(string strIn)
   {
      // Replace linebreak with spaces.
      return Regex.Replace(strIn, "\<linebreak\>", " ");
   }
}
```

or something to that effect